# What is the standard way to handle spaces in path?

Tags: java, windows, installation, path

I have an installer that installs (should install) Tomcat8.5 as a windows service by executing `service.bat`. The following method is used to execute this file.

```
public static String executeCommand__(File directory, Map<String, String> variables, String... commandName)
{
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        
    try
    {
        String line;
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commandName);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            
        if(directory != null)
        {
            pb.directory(directory);
        }
            
        if(variables != null && !variables.isEmpty())
        {
            Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
            //env.clear();
                
            for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : variables.entrySet())
            {
                env.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
            
        Process p = pb.start();
            
        InputStream ins = p.getErrorStream();
        InputStream inps = p.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
            
        BufferedReader b1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
        BufferedReader b2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inps));
        BufferedWriter b3 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
            
        while(true)
        {
            line = b1.readLine();
            if(line != null)
            {
                result.append(line);
                result.append("\n");
            }
                
            line = b2.readLine();
            if(line != null)
            {
                result.append(line);
                result.append("\n");
            }
                
            if(line != null)
            {
                b3.write(line);
            }
                
            if(line == null || line.equals("")) break;
        }
            
        int status = p.waitFor();
            
        if(status != 0)
        {
            log.error("Command execution failed");
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        err.printStackTrace();
        log.error(sw.toString());
    }
    return result == null ? null : result.toString();
}
```

This is how I call the method

```
String installPath = InstallData.getInstance().getInstallPath();
String binDirectory = installPath + "\\EmbeddedTomcat\\bin\\";
String catalinaHome = installPath + "\\EmbeddedTomcat";
File directory = new File(binDirectory);
try
{
    Map<String, String> variables = new HashMap<String, String>();
    variables.put("CATALINA_HOME", catalinaHome);
    executeCommandString = InstallHelper.executeCommand__(directory, variables, installService6);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace(pw);
    log.error(sw.toString());
}
```

When there is no space in installation directory installer works. But when there is `space` in installation directory this code can't install tomcat service. I have tried `""`, `\` and `^` in the following way but got error for each of them. 
For

```
commandName = {"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\App Name\\EmbeddedTomcat\\bin", "service.bat", "install"}
```

I get

```
Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\App Name\EmbeddedTomcat\bin" (in directory "C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"App  Name"\EmbeddedTomcat\bin"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

For

```
commandName = {"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\App Name\\EmbeddedTomcat\\bin\\service.bat", "install"}
```

I get

```
Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\App Name\EmbeddedTomcat\bin\service.bat" (in directory "C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"App Name"\EmbeddedTomcat\bin"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
```

For

```
commandName = {"C:\\Program^ Files^ ^(x86)\\App^ Name\\EmbeddedTomcat\\bin\\service.bat", "install"};
```

I get

```
Cannot run program "C:\Program^ Files^ ^(x86)\App^ Name\EmbeddedTomcat\bin\service.bat" (in directory "C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"App Name"\EmbeddedTomcat\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

For

```
commandName = {"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\App Name\\EmbeddedTomcat\\bin\\service.bat\"", "install"}
```

I get

```
Cannot run program ""C:\Program Files (x86)\App Name\EmbeddedTomcat\bin\service.bat"" (in directory "C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"App Name"\EmbeddedTomcat\bin"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
```

When I run the commands like `C:\Program^ Files^ ^(x86)\App^ Name\EmbeddedTomcat\bin\service.bat install` or `"C:\Program Files (x86)\App Name\EmbeddedTomcat\bin\service.bat" install` manually in cmd they work. But for the same commands installer returns `CreateProcess error = 2 and CreateProcess error = 267`

So do other installers like setup.exe handles `spaces` in file path? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249558/discussion-on-question-by-mahmud-mridul-what-is-the-standard-way-to-handle-space).